# How to update an XML string in a file?

Tags: xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

Platform: MacOS

I've been struggling with getting `xmlstarlet` working and am out of ideas as to why it isn't performing my operation on the sample snippet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/32.0">    
    <filename>Administrator</filename>

    <name>Administrator</name>

    <versionLabel>4.5.0</versionLabel> 
    <versionNumber>1</versionNumber> 

</application>
```

My ultimate goal is to have a script that is run by intelliJ before the build to auto-increment the `<versionNumber>` tag.

It should read in the value, increment it, then write it back.

Something I've done plenty of other times with plistbuddy on other Xcode projects, but using a plain .xml file and the recommended *xmlstarlet* has proven to be frustrating.

Even just trying to write out the value in bash doesn't work for me:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//versionNumber" ./Administrator-app.xml`

sed & awk are really messy for this stuff, but have shown to provide some results.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It's because of the default namespace `http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/32.0`. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775358/xmlstarlet-update-a-value-on-a-specific-node/47777805#47777805 (or any of the other xmlstarlet default namespace questions/answers.)

Comment: @DanielHaley Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[It's not working because the XML is in the default namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777805/7599)

fyi:
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139530992

> " ... In order to handle namespaces with greater ease, XMLStarlet
>   (versions 1.2.1+) will use the namespace prefixes declared on the root
>   element of the input document. The default namespace will be bound to
>   the prefixes "_" and "DEFAULT" (in versions 1.5.0+). So another way to
>   solve handle the previous example would be:"

`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//_:versionNumber" -v . -n Administrator-app.xml`

Result:

`1`